# Convergence in Distribution ($Y \mid N = n)$ is $\chi^2_{2n}$ and $N$ is Poisson($\theta$))

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have a hierarchical model like the following:

- $Y\mid N=n$ is governed by a chi-square distribution with $2n$ degrees of freedom, and
- $\theta$ is governed by a Poisson distribution.

I want to show that as $\theta \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{Y - E[Y]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(Y)}} \rightarrow$ standard normal in distribution.

I know that to show convergence in distribution, I have to show that the pdf (or cdf)
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{X_n}(x) = f_X(x),$$
but I am unsure how to go about this. How could I show that $\frac{Y - E[Y]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(Y)}} \rightarrow$ standard normal in distribution?

Comment: You might note that $\chi^2_{2n}$ is a gamma/Erlang distribution with shape $k$ and rate $\frac12$ so $Y$ is simply the sum of $N$ independent exponential distributions with rate $\frac12$

Comment: Casella Berger 5.36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity I will leave out routine algebra and computations.
Let $\theta$ be fixed with $N$ being Poisson with mean $\theta$. You can first compute the MGF of $Y$ by conditioning on $N$ and using the chi-squared MGF:
$$M_{Y}(t) = E[\exp(tY)] = E[E[\exp(tY) | N]].$$
You can also compute $\mu = E[Y]$ and $\sigma^2 = Var(Y)$ by conditioning on $N$.
Now let
$$X = \frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma}.$$
Simple algebra reveals that the MGF of $X$ is easily obtained from the MGF of $Y$:
$$M_{X}(t) = \exp\left(-\frac{t\mu}{\sigma}\right)M_{Y}\left(\frac{t}{\sigma}\right).$$
After computing $M_X(t)$ you can take the limit as $\theta \to \infty$ and you will find that
$$\lim_{\theta \to \infty}M_{X}(t) = \exp\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right),$$
the standard normal MGF.